# $\{x_{k}\}$ has an accumulation point and $z_k=||x_{k}-x_{k+1}||^2$ is summable, then does $\{x_{n}\}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus

Let $\{x_k\}\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and suppose $\{x_{k}\}$ has an accumulation point and $z_k=||x_{k}-x_{k+1}||^2$ is summable. I was trying to prove that $\{x_{n}\}$ converges, but the best I can prove is  that $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{\left(\sum^{n}_{j=1}||x_{j+1}-x_{j}||\right)^2}{n^2}<\infty$$ using Hardy's Inequality. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Hint: If the $z_k$ are summable, then in particular $|x_k-x_{k+1}|\xrightarrow{k\rightarrow\infty} 0$

Comment: $x_{n}=log(n)$ is such that $x_{n+1}-x_{n}\rightarrow 0$ but $x_n$ does not converge.

Comment: If $x_{n+1} = x_n \pm \frac{1}{n}$, then for almost all collections of choices of sign, every element of $\mathbf{R}$ will be a limit point of $x_n$ (which thus won't converge), but $|x_{n+1} - x_{n}|^2$ is summable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A_k=(1,0)+(\cos\ \theta_k,\sin\ \theta_k)$ s.t. $ |A_k-A_{k+1}| =
\frac{1}{k}$ and $A_k$ is *clockwise* where $|\ |$ is Euclidean
distance in $\mathbb{E}^2$.

That is, $A_k$ is a point in a circle. Clearly, $A_k$ has a
convergent subsequence.

Comment: Yes! This is right! hahaha Thx! it's like the real case, but in here we need to curl real line. =)